# Disable/Enable Ribbon for set time

Tags: javascript, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

I have a plugin for Contact entity that triggers on Create. It then calls the WCF service and creates a new record in the back office (MSSQL). The same entity have another plugin that fires when record is Updated.

Issue I am having is when if I create a new record and within a minute change detail and try to save it, the update plugin fails. This is because the Create plugin is still running. (And the record I am trying to update still doesn't exist in the back office DB)

Is there a way to disable 'Save' or 'Save & Close' button in the ribbon while the status of the Create plugin is not Complete or Failed? Or at least disable it for say 120 Sec so it is not clicked on right away?

CRM 2011 RU18 On Premise. (All end users are restricted to use IE so I can use JS)

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this would be have some JavaScript waiting on the form and not allowing it to save until your plugin has passed in a "complete" message in which case the form can be saved. Near the end of your plugin code i would make it update a value on your form which the JavaScript would look at, if this field isn't populated, don't allow the form to save.

The JavaScript is the easy part using the onSave method and making sure you pass the execution object as the first parameter and assuming you create the field for your plugin a bool

```
function preventSave(exobj)
{
  var pluginFinished = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pluginFinished");

  if (pluginFinished.getValue() == false || pluginFinished.getValue() == null)
  {
    exobj.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
  }
}
```

if there isn't a value or null the JavaScript will not allow the form to save. You may want to provide a message after the preventDefault (prevent save) to alert the uses no save has occurred.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @Jason Roberts question is how will JavaScript will know that I want to check a particular instance of the plugin. For example, if user A creates Contact and that fires off plugin (1st one) and at the same time user B creates a new contact and that fires off plugin too (2nd one). Now in the script for the User A's Contact how can I make sure it is not waiting for the User B's Contact creation? God, I hope I am making sense.

Comment: It made sense, a bit lol, you may need to clarify it further but if i think got the jist of it. The plugin will fire individually for each record, so there could be 10 records created at the same time, thus meaning you plugin would have fired 10 individual times. If you include in your first plugin a piece of code to update a "pluginFinished" field, the JavaScript wont allow the save, no other plugins will be affected. I hope this makes sense and is answering what you were trying to ask? Thanks

Comment: Got it, this has raised hopes! :) Will be trying this first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Great, hope it helps and solves your problem, if you have anymore questions drop me a comment and if it solves your answer please tick my answer. Have a good day

Comment: Got something else added in the task list (As always, urgent!!!) so have to complete that before I get to do this. I will let you know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible.

First you need to clone the save button, hide the native, add the native functionally and the function you need: a disabled rule that calls a js.

In the js you need to ask if the record is created, if not the button should be disable, else enable.

You can make better solution in the javascript asking if the record is created and if not, wait 10 or 15 seconds, the time you want, when the record is created, enable de save button.

Comment: Thanks @Sxntk, Because we have third party solution that uses Ribbon heavily, we try to stay away from any changes in Ribbon area. If nothing work, I might at least at a traffic light style indicator to let user know that their are processes running in background. I will let you know my solution when it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your way and it does works. However, the user experience was affected as while the create plugin is running user wasn't able to save record. Which is what I wanted in a first place. But I tried something else where user can carry on saving but the update plugin joins the queue and waits for the Create plugin to complete. Here is what I did.

1. Created field with two options and set default value to be 'In Progress'. As soon as the record is created the value now is set to In Progress. (true)
2. Added following code right after the data is passed on to the WCF service.

   ```
       // Change Plugin Status flag value
   public void updatePluginStatus(Guid key, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IPluginExecutionContext context)
   {
       IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
       IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
       Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
       contact["contactid"] = key;
       OptionSetValue pluginStatus = new OptionSetValue();
       pluginStatus.Value = 0;
       contact["mw_plugin_status"] = false;

       service.Update(contact);
   }
   ```
3. In my update plugin, I am checking the status for this flag (plugin status) and keep looping until the value changes to false.

   ```
                       while(checkPluginStatus(service, CrmKeyGuid) == true)
                   {
                       checkPluginStatus(service, CrmKeyGuid);
                   }

       //  Check Plugin Status
   public Boolean checkPluginStatus(IOrganizationService service, Guid key)
   {
   Boolean pluginStatus;
   ColumnSet flag = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "mw_plugin_status" });
   var contact = service.Retrieve("contact", key, flag);

       if ((bool)contact["mw_plugin_status"] == true)
   {
       pluginStatus = true;
   }
   else
   {
       pluginStatus = false;
   }
       return pluginStatus;
   }
   ```

Only thing I need to add now is the number of times it loops before throws exception and emails record data so it can be manually amended.

I am no expert at C# and just about get away with my basic needs so please let me know if you see any flow in this logic.

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: btw, the first block of code is in the Create plugin.